# XSLT transforming an xml

Tags: xslt

I am new to xsl. I want to transform an xml from,

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="q">what</str>
    <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>what1</str>
                <str>what2</str>
   </arr>
  </doc>
</result>
```

to,

```
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="q">what</str>
    <str name="suggestion">what1</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="q">what</str>
    <str name="suggestion">what2</str>
  </doc>
</result>
```

I could extract the texts, "what1" and "what2" using,

```
<xsl:template match="/response/result[@name='response']">
             <xsl:for-each select="./doc/arr[@name='suggestion']/str">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$endl"/>
             </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

But I don't know how to enclose the same into output xml format. Can anyone please help...

### Additional feature:

Can anyone please tell if I could add a field to the output doc called `<float name="score">` which would get incremented by 100 with each doc?

eg)
output:

```
   <response>
      <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
          <str name="indent">on</str>
          <str name="q">"what"</str>
        </lst>
      </lst>
      <result numFound="2" name="response" start="0">
        <doc>
          <str name="query">what</str>
          <str>what1</str>
          <float name="score">100</float>
        </doc>
        <doc>
          <str name="query">what</str>
          <str>what2</str>
          <float name="score">200</float>
        </doc>
        <doc>
          <str name="query">what</str>
          <str>what3</str>
          <float name="score">300</float>
        </doc>
      </result>
    </response>
```

Can you please tell what function do I suppose to use?

Comment: Generally I would recommend this: Take a target xml file and wrap the xsl:stylesheets and xsl:template match="/" around it. Then go on and replace the contents with your xsl:value-of/for-each tags etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the OP's comment that updates the question:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="result">
  <result numFound="{count(doc/arr/str)}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='numFound')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </result>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="arr[@name='suggestion']/str">
  <doc>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../../str"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </doc>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="doc|doc/arr">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="doc/str "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following (provided in the OP's comment) XML document**:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="q">"what"</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="q">what</str>
            <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>what1</str>
                <str>what2</str>
            </arr>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">1</int>
      <lst name="params">
         <str name="indent">on</str>
         <str name="q">"what"</str>
      </lst>
   </lst>
   <result numFound="2" name="response" start="0">
      <doc>
         <str name="q">what</str>
         <str>what1</str>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="q">what</str>
         <str>what2</str>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

**Update**:

In an update to his question, the OP requested:

> Can anyone please tell if I could add a field to the output doc called
>   `<float name="score">` which would get incremented by 100 with each
>   doc?

**This is extremely easy to achieve**. We add just three lines of code to the existing transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="result">
    <result numFound="{count(doc/arr/str)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='numFound')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="arr[@name='suggestion']/str">
    <doc>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../str"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <float name="score">
         <xsl:value-of select="100*position()"/>
        </float>    
    </doc>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="doc|doc/arr">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="doc/str "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to this XML document**:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="q">"what"</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="q">what</str>
            <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>what1</str>
                <str>what2</str>
                <str>what3</str>
            </arr>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">1</int>
      <lst name="params">
         <str name="indent">on</str>
         <str name="q">"what"</str>
      </lst>
   </lst>
   <result numFound="3" name="response" start="0">
      <doc>
         <str name="q">what</str>
         <str>what1</str>
         <float name="score">100</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="q">what</str>
         <str>what2</str>
         <float name="score">200</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="q">what</str>
         <str>what3</str>
         <float name="score">300</float>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

Comment: This one just gave the exact output. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I didn't understood that the output should be embedded in the original XML. The classic "copy + override for specific nodes" is indeed the required approach then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. May be I should have mentioned that bit more clearer in the question.
Also trying to understand the xslt functions you used..

Comment: @sriram: What "float field"?, no counters are needed, in my solution I use the standard XPath function `count()`.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: The float field is not a part of input. It is used to specify that the first matching suggestion needs to have a score of 100, second one 200 and so on. Based on the order of suggestion, we just would want to assign these scores in ascending order with an increment of 100.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I have mentioned about that float field in my question. Just added that sometime ago under "Additional feature" heading. I thought it would be same in xsl as in java to use a counter in a loop and increment that value by 100 with each suggestion. Or is it different? Can you please tell what needs to be done to have that updated ouput?
Meanwhile trying to understand your xsl..

Comment: @sriram: I am at work now. Will have time to look at this in 7-8 hours.

Comment: @sriram: just add before the closing `</doc>` tag this: `<float name="score"> <xsl:value-of select="100*position()"/> </float>` I will update my answer now.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I understood the logic and syntaxes used in your xsl :) But now I am looking for <xsl:for-each> that would iterate from start value to end value. If you have any suggestions can you please update.. I have posted more info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180816/how-to-do-xslfor-each-on-a-counter-and-xslvariable-default-value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5130/discussion-between-sriram-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Answer (score 3):

The following stylesheet produces the desired result from your input. It might be too lenient or too strict, but since I don't know your exact requirements or have a schema for the input, it's a best effort. Please use this as a starting point but do proper testing and investigate the meaning of what I provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="numFound"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc/arr[@name='suggestion']/str)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/arr[@name='suggestion']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="arr[@name='suggestion']">
        <xsl:for-each select="str">
            <doc>
                <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()/preceding-sibling:: str[@name='q']" />
                <xsl:variable name="nameAttributeValue" select="parent::node()/@name" />
                <xsl:element name="str"><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$nameAttributeValue" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:element>
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:** In response to your comment: notice how my first template matches on `/*`. This comes down to "any root element". If an XPath expression starts with a single `/`, it's always relative to the document root. If it starts with a double `//` it basically means anywhere in the current node. If it doesn't start with a slash, it's relative to the current node.

In order to process the XML as in your comment, you'd need to change the stylesheet to...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/response/result">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="numFound"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc/arr[@name='suggestion']/str)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/arr[@name='suggestion']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="arr[@name='suggestion']">
        <xsl:for-each select="str">
            <doc>
                <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()/preceding-sibling:: str[@name='q']" />
                <xsl:variable name="nameAttributeValue" select="parent::node()/@name" />
                <xsl:element name="str"><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$nameAttributeValue" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:element>
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That first template I added is to make sure we override some default template hidden in XSLT. Mind that this will only provide correct output if there's only a single `result` element in `response`.

Like I stated, please learn the use of XSLT and XPath expressions to make sure you understand what's going on in the stylesheet.

Comment: Yep it does. In case you wanted to see/test it: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/3vIPuM

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it would work for,

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="q">"what"</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="q">what</str>
    <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>what1</str>
                <str>what2</str>
   </arr>
  </doc>
</result>
</response>

But in this case I am getting ,
<response numFound="0"></response>

Please help. Thanks in advance