# how to do <xsl:for-each> on a counter and <xsl:variable> default value

Tags: xslt

This post is an extension of [XSLT transforming an xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167199/xslt-transforming-an-xml).

In this resultant xml got in the above mentioned post, I want to have features like rows and start.

For example) If as a part of input I am giving

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="q">"what"</str>
      <str name="rows">2</str>
      <str name="start">1</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="query">what</str>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <str>what1</str>
        <str>what2</str>
        <str>what3</str>
        <str>what4</str>
        <str>what5</str>
      </arr>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

by using the mentioned xsl in the previous post mentioned above, I can get the output,

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="q">"what"</str>
            <!--str name="rows">
        2</str>
        <str name="start">1</str-->
    </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numfound="5" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="query">what</str>
        <str name="suggestion">what1</str>
        <float name="score">100</float>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="query">what</str>
        <str name="suggestion">what2</str>
        <float name="score">200</float>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="query">what</str>
        <str name="suggestion">what3</str>
        <float name="score">300</float>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="query">what</str>
        <str name="suggestion">what4</str>
        <float name="score">400</float>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="query">what</str>
        <str name="suggestion">what5</str>
        <float name="score">500</float>
    </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

and when I give start = 2 then I am expecting suggestions to start from what3 after leaving out 0 and 1st suggestion.

Also when I give rows=1, it means I should get only one result starting from "start" position

Also I want to make sure to have default values for rows and start. Hence on browsing net I could find this post: http://remysharp.com/2008/08/15/how-to-default-a-variable-in-xslt/

Is there a better way of specifying a default value for a variable, like using something like default attribute? I tried using default attribute. But seems it doesn't use that.

Also I could see a `<xsl:for-each>` iterating over an array. But I don't know how to make it having start values and end values, like if start is 2 and rows is 2 then I want some thing like,

```
<xsl:for-each select="counter" start="$start" end = "$end">
<doc>
 <str name="query">what</str>
 <str name="suggestion"><xsl:value-of select="//arr[@name='suggestion'][start]"</str>
</doc>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any suggestions please...

**My solution:**

Tried more and finally happy to learn few things about xsl :) Thanks to Dimitre and G_H(from previous post)..

**XSL created:**

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
          <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/response/result">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="numFound"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc/arr[@name='suggestion']/str)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/arr[@name='suggestion']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="arr[@name='suggestion']">
   <xsl:variable name="rows" as="xs:integer">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='rows']"><xsl:value-of select="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='rows']"/></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>10</xsl:otherwise> <!-- default value -->
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="start" as="xs:integer">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='start']"><xsl:value-of select="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='rows']"/></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise> <!-- default value -->
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="str">          
          <xsl:if test="position()-1 &gt;= $start and position() &lt;= $rows+$start">
            <doc>
                <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()/preceding-sibling:: str[@name='query']" />
                <xsl:variable name="nameAttributeValue" select="parent::node()/@name" />
                <xsl:element name="str"><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$nameAttributeValue" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:element>
                      <float name="score">
                           <xsl:value-of select="100*position()"/>
                      </float>

            </doc>

            </xsl:if>     
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
 <response>
      <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
          <str name="indent">on</str>
          <str name="q">"what"</str>
           <str name="rows">2</str>
          <str name="start">2</str>     
        </lst>
      </lst>
      <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
          <str name="query">what</str>
          <arr name="suggestion">
            <str>what1</str>
            <str>what2</str>
            <str>what3</str>
            <str>what4</str>
            <str>what5</str>
          </arr>
        </doc>
      </result>
    </response>
```

**Output**

```
 <response>
        <lst name="responseHeader">
            <int name="status">0</int>
            <int name="QTime">1</int>
            <lst name="params">
                <str name="indent">on</str>
                <str name="q">"what"</str>
                <str name="rows">2</str>
                <str name="start">2</str>
            </lst>
        </lst>
        <result name="response" numfound="5" start="0">
            <doc>
                <str name="query">what</str>
                <str name="suggestion">what3</str>
                <float name="score">300</float>
            </doc>
            <doc>
                <str name="query">what</str>
                <str name="suggestion">what4</str>
                <float name="score">400</float>
            </doc>
        </result>
    </response>
```

Finally I might be needed to change the numfound parameter based on the given number of docs. 
Again thanks a lot for your guidance:)

Comment: I could get the value of variables using,

<xsl:variable name="rows" as="xs:integer" select="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='rows']" />
  <xsl:variable name="start" as="xs:integer" select="/response/lst/lst/str[@name='start']" />

I am also able to use it in my code. But don't know how to use the same in <xsl:for-each> to select corresponding indexed suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 transformation that produces the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pdefStart" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
 <xsl:param name="pdefRows" as="xs:integer"  select="9999999"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStart" as="xs:integer" select=
  "(/*/lst/lst/str[@name='start'],
    $pdefStart
    )
     [1]
  "/>

 <xsl:variable name="vRows" as="xs:integer" select=
  "(/*/lst/lst/str[@name='rows'],
    $pdefRows
    )
     [1]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="result">
    <result numFound=
       "{count(doc/arr/str
              [position() ge $vStart
             and
              position() lt $vStart + $vRows
               ]
               )}"
         start="{$vStart}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "arr[@name='suggestion']/str
          [position() ge $vStart
         and
           position() lt $vStart + $vRows
          ]">
    <doc>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../str"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <float name="score">
         <xsl:value-of select="100*position()"/>
        </float>
    </doc>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="doc|doc/arr">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="str"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (based on the provided, but with more "interesting" values for `rows` and `start`):

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="q">"what"</str>
      <str name="rows">3</str>
      <str name="start">2</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="query">what</str>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <str>what1</str>
        <str>what2</str>
        <str>what3</str>
        <str>what4</str>
        <str>what5</str>
      </arr>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">1</int>
      <lst name="params"/>
   </lst>
   <result numFound="3" start="2">
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what2</str>
         <float name="score">200</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what3</str>
         <float name="score">300</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what4</str>
         <float name="score">400</float>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

**The defaults in the transformation are set in such a way that** if no `start` is specified in the XML document, we assume `start = 1` and if no `rows` is specified, we assume `rows = 9999999` -- that is, in the default case we want to get as many `str` elements as there are in the document.

**Here is an example**:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="q">"what"</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="query">what</str>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <str>what1</str>
        <str>what2</str>
        <str>what3</str>
        <str>what4</str>
        <str>what5</str>
      </arr>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

**This document has no `rows` and `start` and when processed with the above transformation, the defaults are used, producing**:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">1</int>
      <lst name="params"/>
   </lst>
   <result numFound="5" start="1">
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what1</str>
         <float name="score">100</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what2</str>
         <float name="score">200</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what3</str>
         <float name="score">300</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what4</str>
         <float name="score">400</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="query">what</str>
         <str>what5</str>
         <float name="score">500</float>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

**Finally, do note**: For maximum flexibility the defaults are specified as global parameters and can be passed externally to the transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) I also learnt more about this and created an xsl. Posted that in my answer below. Thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: I could't answer to my own question as it is less than 8 hrs :(. But after 8 hrs I will post the xsl which I designed based on your guidance. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @sriram: You are welcome. I am not sure if it is a good practice to answer your own questions. I'd recommend editing your question and putting the answer you naow have, at the very end of the question.

Comment: Updated my solution at the end of my question. I don't currently require to change the value of numfound in the output xml. If needed I will use your logic for that. :)

Comment: @sriram: Great! I'm leaving for work now but will have a look when I find free time.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. Editing the solution into the question means you have no way of marking your question as "solved" by accepting an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF: ??? You have accepted an answer already (in this case). Don't you think asking a question and then posting an answer that you accept is "unethical" at the bare minimum?

Comment: Dimitre it is perfectly acceptable for an OP to answer and accept his or her own answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/